# Facebook Share Button disabled

Tags: android, facebook-share, facebook-sdk-4.x

I upgraded the Facebook ShareButton from 4.5.0 to 4.16.1 and now the ShareButton is disabled. I have to support back to Android API level 9, and I just want to use the ShareButton from the Facebook SDK. With 4.5, it was working well.

Here is Facebook Activity from the manifest, I don't use a provider:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    tools:replace="android:theme" />
```

FB Button onClick listener:

```
facebookShareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentDescription(preview)
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(url))
            .build();
        shareDialog.show(content);
    }
});
```

I initialize the Facebook SDK in my Application class like this:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
```

Why doesn't it work after upgrading the SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your content to share while implementing Share option in Facebook sdk. So set the content while defining the share button.

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
            .build();
fbShareButton.setShareContent(content);
```